# Traefik v2.6 multiple certresolvers

Tags: traefik

I am running Traefik and first I configured to use cloudflare as my certresolver for domain1.com. But I have domain2.net hosted on Route 53.
This is what I have so far:

```
--entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.certresolver=cloudflare
--entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.domains[0].main=local.domain1.com
--entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.domains[0].sans=*.local.domain1.com
--certificatesresolvers.cloudflare.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare
--certificatesresolvers.cloudflare.acme.email=myemail@gmail.com
--certificatesresolvers.cloudflare.acme.dnschallenge.resolvers=1.1.1.1
--certificatesresolvers.cloudflare.acme.storage=/certs/acme.json
--entrypoints.websecure.web.tls.domains[1].main=local.domain2.net
--entrypoints.websecure.web.tls.domains[1].sans=*.local.domain2.net
--certificatesresolvers.route53.acme.dnschallenge.provider=route53
--certificatesresolvers.route53.acme.email=myemail@gmail.com
--certificatesresolvers.route53.acme.storage=/certs/acme.json
```

But when I setup this way, only route53 is configured as a certificate resolver. That's because it's being called last.
Is there a way to make this work with multiple certificate resolvers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figure this out and forgot to update.
So just create additional args on traefik deployment:

```
        - --certificatesresolvers.cloudflare.acme.dnschallenge.provider=cloudflare
        - --certificatesresolvers.cloudflare.acme.email=myemail@gmail.com
        - --certificatesresolvers.cloudflare.acme.dnschallenge.resolvers=1.1.1.1
        - --certificatesresolvers.cloudflare.acme.storage=/certs/cloudflare.json
        - --certificatesresolvers.route53.acme.dnschallenge.provider=route53
        - --certificatesresolvers.route53.acme.email=myemail@gmail.com
        - --certificatesresolvers.route53.acme.storage=/certs/route53.json
```

And then the entrypoints you add to the annotation of the app deployment with its own domain.